# System's clang installation won't link

Tags: c, unix, clang, ld, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 12 (based on Ubuntu 11.10) and installed clang compiler with the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install clang
```

What installs a system-wide clang-2.9. But when i try compile something with it, I get this error:

```
$ clang -o hello hello.c 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the linker invocation I get using the `-v` flag:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o teste crt1.o crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../.. /tmp/cc-oYpj2E.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtend.o crtn.o
```

So, what is this problem and how can I work around it?

Comment: Have you tried running `ldconfig`?

Comment: Seems like a package bug in Ubuntu Oneiric (from which Mint 12 is based on) (see [clang can’t link any programs: cannot find crt1.o, crti.o, crtn.o](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/clang/+bug/792146)).